# How to Convert Python Code to Java without numpy

Tags: java, android, python, arrays, opencv

I have a method in Python that makes use of OpenCV to remove the background from an image. I want the same functionality to work with android's version of OpenCV but I just cant seem to wrap my head around how the arrays work and how I can process them.

This is what I have so far in Java :

```
private Bitmap GetForeground(Bitmap source){
        source = scale(source,300,300);
        Mat mask = Mat.zeros(source.getHeight(),source.getWidth(),CvType.CV_8U);
        Mat bgModel = Mat.zeros(1,65,CvType.CV_64F);
        Mat ftModel = Mat.zeros(1,65,CvType.CV_64F);
        int x = (int)Math.round(source.getWidth()*0.1);
        int y = (int)Math.round(source.getHeight()*0.1);
        int width = (int)Math.round(source.getWidth()*0.8);
        int height = (int)Math.round(source.getHeight()*0.8);
        Rect rect = new Rect(x,y, width,height);
        Mat sourceMat = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(source, sourceMat);
        Imgproc.grabCut(sourceMat, mask, rect, bgModel, ftModel, 5, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);

        int frameSize=sourceMat.rows()*sourceMat.cols();
        byte[] buffer= new byte[frameSize];
        mask.get(0,0,buffer);
        for (int i = 0; i < frameSize; i++) {
            if (buffer[i] == 2 || buffer[i] == 0){
                buffer[i] = 0;
            }else{
                buffer[i] = 1 ;
            }
        }

        byte[][] sourceArray = getMultiChannelArray(sourceMat);
        byte[][][] reshapedMask = ReshapeArray(buffer, sourceMat.rows(), sourceMat.cols());
        return source;
    }

    private byte[][][] ReshapeArray(byte[] arr, int rows, int cols){
        byte[][][] out = new byte[cols][rows][1];
        int index=0;

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                out[i][j][0] = arr[index];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    public static byte[][] getMultiChannelArray(Mat m) {
        //first index is pixel, second index is channel
        int numChannels=m.channels();//is 3 for 8UC3 (e.g. RGB)
        int frameSize=m.rows()*m.cols();
        byte[] byteBuffer= new byte[frameSize*numChannels];
        m.get(0,0,byteBuffer);

        //write to separate R,G,B arrays
        byte[][] out=new byte[frameSize][numChannels];
        for (int p=0,i = 0; p < frameSize; p++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < numChannels; n++,i++) {
                out[p][n]=byteBuffer[i];
            }
        }
        return out;
    }
```

The python code I want to recreate :

```
image = cv2.imread('Images/handheld.jpg')
image = imutils.resize(image, height = 300)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
frModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
height, width, d = np.array(image).shape
rect = (int(width*0.1),int(height*0.1),int(width*0.8),int(height*0.8))
cv2.grabCut(image, mask, rect, bgModel,frModel, 5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
mask = np.where((mask==2) | (mask == 0),0,1).astype('uint8')
image = image*mask[:,:,np.newaxis]
```

I have no idea how to convert the last two lines of the python code. If there is a way to just run python clean on an android device within my own project that would also be awesome.

Comment: No, you cannot just run python on Android. You have to write the relevant Java code for this purpose.

Comment: @ZdaR not even with Jython for Android or Qpython ?

Comment: And unrelated: stick to java naming convents. Java method names should go camelCase(). Also note that Java doesn't have "real" multi-dimensional arrays, so expect (negative) surprises regarding performance. It is possible to write high performance "computation code" in java, but that is like a science of its own.

Comment: @ZdaR You have any idea how to do it in the particular case? I'm kinda new to python and not the best at Java

Comment: @Corentin Jython code work. But don't forget that libraries like numpy draw their performance from the fact that all the core computational stuff ... is all implemented in C. So, when you find a way to get that library compiled for Android, you maybe have a chance with jython ;-)

Comment: @Corentin I am not too worried about performance at the time. I really just want to see if itll work

Comment: @GhostCat Totally agree :-) But like he didn't talk about performance, those solution came up to my mind. But it would be definitively faster to implement the solution in java

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you should consider talking a look to SL4A project which would allow you run your Python code on Android through java app.

Here are interesting links :

1. https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a
2. https://norwied.wordpress.com/2012/04/11/run-sl4a-python-script-from-within-android-app/
3. http://jokar-johnk.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-make-android-app-with-sl4a.html

Answer (score 1):

Let's see both the commands and try to convert them to Java API calls. It may not be simple 2 line in code.

`mask = np.where((mask==2) | (mask == 0),0,1).astype('uint8')`

In the above command, we are creating a new image `mask` which has `uint` data type of  pixel values. The new `mask` matrix would have value `0` for every position where previous `mask` has a value of either `2` or `0`, otherwise `1`. Let's demonstrate this with an example:

```
mask = [
[0, 1, 1, 2],
[1, 0, 1, 3],
[0, 1, 1, 2],
[2, 3, 1, 0],
]
```

After this operation the output would be:

```
mask = [
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0],
]
```

So this above command is simply generating a binary mask with only 0 and 1 values. This can replicated in `Java` using `Core.compare()` method as:

```
// Get a mask for all `1` values in matrix.
Mat mask1vals;
Core.compare(mask, new Scalar(1), mask1vals, Core.CMP_EQ);

// Get a mask for all `3` values in matrix.
Mat mask3vals;
Core.compare(mask, new Scalar(3), mask3vals, Core.CMP_EQ);

// Create a combined mask
Mat foregroundMask;
Core.max(mask1vals, mask3vals, foregroundMask)
```

Now you need to multiply this foreground mask with the input image, to get final grabcut image as:

```
// First convert the single channel mat to 3 channel mat
Imgproc.cvtColor(foregroundMask, foregroundMask, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
// Now simply take min operation
Mat out;
Core.min(foregroundMask, image, out);
```